# Make: How pre-requs are creating automatically?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new to make. I am trying to debug some issue. For that i kept some debug statements to know all pre-reqs of particular target.

Eg:

```
$(TARGET_BUILD)/%.o: $(TARGET_BUILD)/%.c
     $(info pre-res for this target $^)
     $(c_dependency)
```

After completion of the build. When i check the build log i can see there are several '.h' files listed in prerequisites. From the above target we mentioned only '.c' ($(TARGET_BUILD)/%.c) files as pre-reqs right? Then how come it is showing header files in pre-reqs. Are they auto generated? If yes, Can you please help me how they are created automatically.

FYI, $(c_dependency) is a define directive which has below lines defined :

```
mkdir -p $(@D)

$(CC64) -o $(@) -c $(CFLAGS64) $<
```

Comment: You probably have other rules without recipe, elsewhere in this Makefile or in another Makefile included by this one, that declare header files as prerequisites of object files.

Comment: Yeah,Seems like. But there are lot of make files in this vast project. Is there a way to know from where that rule is hitting ? I mean from which make file its hitting?

Comment: `find` and `grep`? But beware, some of these included Makefiles may be generated by make itself; before searching them you will have to make sure that they exist already. Moreover, make can also generate dependencies dynamically (using the `$(eval...)` function); if it is the case searching files will probably not work. You could also use the `--debug=v` make option to see what makefiles are parsed.